# I would like to ask for a revision whether this question could be reopened

Tags: discussion, support

I have asked a question recently, which got closed as duplicate:

[Extra wear of multicore processor when only a single core is used. Is there such a thing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1626879/extra-wear-of-multicore-processor-when-only-a-single-core-is-used-is-there-such)

I believe that the post that was suggested to contain answers, do not in fact contain an answer to my specific concern, but deals with things in a way more generic level.

I am ready to acknowledge that the answer to my question could be a simple, or a more verbose variant of a "No."

Yet, I feel such questions still have place on a question/answer website. Even a "No" answer has significance and value.

I request — if there is such a possibility — the question to be reopened; I would like to learn more about the raised topic.

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I request — if there is such a possibility — the question to be reopened

Meta is not really the right place to start when asking for a reopen:

> If you see a question and do not agree that it truly is a duplicate, **edit it to highlight the differences**, then try to [get it reopened](https://superuser.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions) by [casting a reopen vote](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Source: [Why are some questions marked as duplicate? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/duplicates)

You have already edit the question, so it is in the reopen queue where users with the required reputation can vote to reopen it.

In this particular case I have reopened it (but normally you should wait for the reopen queue to do it's thing).